# Is it possible to mark a module function as "hidden" from Intellisense discovery?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, f#

As a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824536/is-there-any-good-way-for-an-inline-function-to-access-private-or-internal-values) question, I am wondering whether it is possible to mark an F# function within a module (presumably via an attribute) as "hidden" from Intellisense. To recap, I have some functions which are marked `inline` but are implemented in terms of other functions I don't really want to expose. So while the implementation functions must be kept public (since they are being inlined), I remember that in the past I've come across C# methods which were hidden from Visual Studio Intellisense but compiled just fine if you knew what they were, but I don't remember the exact method(s) and am unsure if that was some sort of ad-hoc Visual Studio thing or a usable feature like `DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)` awareness.

**Update:** I tried applying the `EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)` but it doesn't appear to work in Visual F# projects.

Comment: One option is to put the 'helper' functions inside a namespace or class with name containing 'Internal'.  The functions are available for use if a client really wants to use them, but at least now they are partitioned off into an area where a client of the library can see they weren't intended for direct use.

Comment: @Dan Bryant - indeed, that is the current solution I've been using, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to do that recently and I'm pretty sure that F# ignores the `EditorBrowsable` attribute.

The only way to make declaration disappear from the IntelliSense is to use the `ObsoleteAttribute`, but that also means you'll get a warning when you actually use the function. This is a bit unfortunate, but it may be okay if you use the function only from some implementation file where you can disable the warning:

Declaration in one file:

```
module Internal = 
  [<System.ObsoleteAttribute>]
  let foo = 10
```

Implementation file that disables warnings and uses `foo`:

```
// Disable 'obsolete' warning
#nowarn "44"

// 'Internal' is empty (and is not shown in the completion list)
Internal.foo
```

The attribute can be applied to modules, functions and types, so it is quite flexible.

Comment: I'll file a bug about F# not honoring EditorBrowsable.

Comment: FYI - F# in VS2012 still ignores the EditorBrowsable attribute (but the ObsoleteAttribute is still a usable workaround).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`, but this will only work for clients of your assembly that are not in the same solution (i.e. importing your class library as an assembly and not as a Project.)  Projects in the same solution will still show the methods in Intellisense.