# Is there a way to use let statements in classes with inline methods?

Tags: f#

A simplified example that gives an error because `let str` is private:

```
let launch = printfn "%s"

type Test() =
    let str = "Hello"
    member inline t.A() = 
        launch str
```

I've discovered statically resolved type parameters in F# and after a rewrite have a neural net library where 95% of the functions are inlined as a result, including class methods. I wrote it as a F# script at first, forgetting that there is a difference between script mode and compiled mode in their treatment of inlined methods.

```
let test = // Is this the only choice?
    let str = "Hello"
    fun () ->
        launch str
```

Is there any way to use body initializers in F# classes or should I rewrite the classes to be higher order functions like the above? Thankfully, that would not be a problem here.

[This question is related to this one, but I thought I'd ask again since it has been 5 years.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824536/is-there-any-good-way-for-an-inline-function-to-access-private-or-internal-value)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was wrong. It is true that the higher order function example does work in the simplified case above, but I've realized that lambda arguments cannot be statically resolved. I thought of using records for a bit and then tried this:

```
type Test() =
    let str = "Hello"

    member t.Str = str
    member inline t.A() = 
        launch t.Str
```

Private member can be exposed and this will compile. Doing it like the above would be satisfactory.

Comment: You didn't actually make it private – does `member private t.Str = str` work?

Comment: Only F# script mode, not interactive. I wouldn't mind a way to make let statements public in classes without having to expose them via members. In fact, if str was not `string`, but `^a` I would not be able to expose it because it would escape the scope. I had to use records to get around this. Actually this might be worth another SO question...Actually, on further examination it is just a complex case I am having. I would be able to expose via the above method if `str: 'a`